# Insert Into Returning True but Not Inserting Data

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a function that first checks to see a row exists and if it doesn't it inserts data. If anything fails it is supposed to return false. When I run the function and check the return with a var_dump, it returns true. I'm to assume that the data is inserted into the database, but it is not. Why would it do this? Is there something wrong with my function?

```
function add_tier ($mysqli, $project_id, $tier_number, $wanted, $in_return, $limit) {

    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(tier_id) FROM `tier` WHERE `project_id` 
    = $project_id AND `tier_number` = $tier_number")){

      if ($return < 1) {

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `tier` (`project_id`, 
        `tier_number`, `wanted`, `in_return`, `limit`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){

        $stmt->bind_param('iissi', $project_id, $tier_number, $wanted, $in_return, 
        $limit);

        $return = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

        return $return;

        } else {return false;}      

      } else {return false;}            

    }  else {return false;}

}
```

Comment: Is the unique key on both fields, or are there two keys, one on each?

Comment: `tier_id` is the only unique key. It is also the primary key.

Comment: Where is the `$return` in `if($return<1)` defined?

Comment: Ahh, that's it. Put that as the answer and I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Continuing from comments) You don't appear to have defined the `$return` in this line anywhere:

```
if ($return < 1) {
```